# Retrieving Generic List Item index

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a list as below. I would like to retrieve the indexes of all the items which have the value 1.

```
        List<int> listFilter = new List<int>();

        listFilter.Add(1);
        listFilter.Add(0);
        listFilter.Add(0);
        listFilter.Add(1);
```

I should be getting 0 and 3 for the sample data above.

The code below gives me an object of [value, index] pair. How do I modify this to just output a list which has only the indexes.

```
        var val = listFilter.Select((value, index) => new { Value = value, Index = index }).Where(item => item.Value == 1).ToList();
```

Thanks

Regards,
Balan Sinniah

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that in the initial `Select` clause you returned an anonymous type.  To get back out the value you need an additional `Select` later on to filter back to that value.

```
var val = listFilter
  .Select((value, index) => new { Value = value, Index = index })
  .Where(item => item.Value == 1)
  .Select(item => item.Index)
  .ToList();
```

Comment: The first select isn't needed. listFilter.Where(value => value == 1).Select((value, index) => index).ToList() is the same.

Comment: @samjudson That was my first thought too but when I tried it out I got 0,1 as the answer not 0,3.  The problem is that the where() creates a new enumerable with only 2 entries and when we select the indices from *that* we get 0,1.  The first select it needs to capture the index from the original list.

Comment: Ah yes, as the Where creates a new list, so the second index is the index in the second list, not the index in the first list. My mistake.